# Is there a price comparison search engine for van rental like there is for cars?

Tags: online-resources, car-rentals

I am planning a road trip in Europe. I would like to rent a van though. It would be more flexible for my trip.

I know plenty search engines for cars, some with very good results, but none specifically for vans.

Does such thing exist or do I have to contact the renting companoies directly or via their sites?

Comment: Searching "Van Hire Comparison" on google.co.uk got me a whole bunch - but they were all UK only, not global like say, skyscanner's. Likley there are others for wheverever you wish to hire. Also, the best deals for vans are sometimes local companies focussed on commercial hire, who may not be on major comparsion sites.

Comment: The OP doesn't specify, but the UK is probably a bad place from which to hire a van to visit mainland Europe. Some companies prohibit taking their vehicles to mainland Europe, and all prices are very high. I am led to believe that this is because of the number of vans impounded by HM Customs on their return to the UK full of cheap booze and cigarettes.

Comment: @DaveP - wasn't implying that it was. A bigger issue to me would be that the driver is on the wrong side for driving in most of Europe. Was merely indicating that there may be national variations, depending on where OP is starting from.

Comment: @CMaster Completely agree with you. Was just adding a bit of personal experience from hiring a van in the UK to go to France.

Answer (score 2):

You could look at the [Kayak Car Search](https://www.kayak.com/cars). I tried for a few European combinations and it came up with various van and van-like options in it's 'Car Types' filter. Although, to be fair, the options seem to be limited in some places.

Helpfully they offer a list of other sites and invite you to compare Kayak against them.

[Priceline](http://www.priceline.com/rentalcars), [Orbitz](http://www.orbitz.com/), [Travelocity](https://www.travelocity.com/), [AutoEurope](http://www.autoeurope.com/car.cfm) and [CarRentals.com](http://www.carrentals.com/) all allow you to filter on type and find a few large vans and some smaller passenger vans / SUVs.

Note, I think you want a 'real' van rather than what those sites might be calling a 'van' which is more an SUV. But some of them did match genuine vans of the type you may be looking for.